# GFCI Kitchen Circuit(s)

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, electrical-distribution

I understand that all wall receptacles (including counters) must be GFCI protected in a kitchen with a combined dining area but how about a separate dining area/room receptacles (separated from kitchen by partition wall including breakfast bar in wall)?

This is how it is currently wired (one circuit from distribution box through dining area [currently GFCI] terminating on one kitchen counter same GFCI circuit). Was this originally done (builder) for convenience/cost (all receptacles on one 20A GFCI circuit for dining room receptacles and including the one 20A kitchen counter) or must the dining area wall receptacles also be GFCI?

This is a 100A service condominium in Montgomery County MD.

Comment: There certainly is no problem if the GFCI's cover more outlets than just those at the counter.

Answer (score 1):

This was something the builder just did (I wouldn't even call it convenience/cost, for that matter).

We start with 210.52(B)(1):

> **(1) Receptacle Outlets Served.** In the kitchen, pantry,
>   breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling
>   unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch
>   circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and
>   floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all counter-
>   top outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for
>   refrigeration equipment.

and 210.11(C)(1):

> **(1) Small-Appliance Branch Circuits.** In addition to the
>   number of branch circuits required by other parts of this
>   section, two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits shall be provided for all receptacle outlets specified by
>   210.52(B).

Between these two sections, we can establish that the dining room outlets are part of the *small-appliance* branch circuits, not the general lighting load.

However, 210.8(A) point 6:

> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and
>   20-ampere receptacles installed in the locations specified in
>   210.8(A)(1) through (10) shall have ground-fault circuit-
>   interrupter protection for personnel.
>
> (6) Kitchens - where the receptacles are installed to
>   serve the countertop surfaces

requires only that the receptacles installed to serve the countertop surfaces in the kitchen be GFCI protected.  This means that *no other receptacles* on the small appliance branch circuits require GFCI protection under the 2014 NEC, regardless if they are located in the kitchen proper or in a separate dining room.